# Android: No class definition found error

Tags: button, maps, android-intent

this is a screen with two buttons to show satellite view and street view of maps. the modules of streetview and SatelliteView work perfectly fine separately. but when included in a single app with two buttons(intent) it shows the following errors. please help

```
10-16 16:33:20.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 16:33:20.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15483): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.uhcl.maps.StreetView
10-16 16:33:20.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15483):     at com.uhcl.maps.MymenuActivity.onClick(MymenuActivity.java:39)
10-16 16:33:20.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15483):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
10-16 16:33:20.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15483):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-16 16:33:20.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15483):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-16 16:33:20.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15483):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-16 16:33:20.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
10-16 16:33:20.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 16:33:20.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-16 16:33:20.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-16 16:33:20.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-16 16:33:20.400: WARN/ActivityManager(130):   Force finishing activity com.uhcl.maps/.MymenuActivity
```

this is my Activity class

```
package com.uhcl.maps;`
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MymenuActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button satelliteviwb1, streetviewb2, floormapb3;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    satelliteviwb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    streetviewb2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    floormapb3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.flooricon);
    satelliteviwb1.setOnClickListener(this);
    streetviewb2.setOnClickListener(this);
    floormapb3.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {


    case R.id.b1:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MymenuActivity.this, SatelliteView.class);
        // Intent intent = new Intent("com.uhcl.maps.SATELLITEVIEW");
        MymenuActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    case R.id.b2:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MymenuActivity.this, StreetView.class);
        // Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.uhcl.maps.STREETVIEW");
        MymenuActivity.this.startActivity(intent2);

    case R.id.flooricon:
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(MymenuActivity.this, FloorView.class);
        // Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.uhcl.maps.STREETVIEW");
        MymenuActivity.this.startActivity(intent3);

    }


    }
}
```

and this is my map activity

```
package com.uhcl.maps;    
import java.util.List;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class SatelliteView extends MapActivity {

public MapView mapView;
public CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;
public Drawable drawable;
public List<Overlay> mapOverlays;


public MyLocationOverlay compass;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

     drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

 itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(
            drawable, this);

    //Latitude and Longitude 
    Float sscbla = 29.5843F;
    Float sscblo = -95.098983F;
    Float deltala = 29.577683F;
    Float deltalo = -95.104208F;
    Float csbla = 29.585831F;
    Float csblo = -95.094133F;
    Float arbourla = 29.577933F;
    Float arbourlo = -95.102219F;
    //Float bayoula= F;
    //Float bayoulo= F;

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (deltala * 1E6),
            (int) (deltalo * 1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello",
            "I'm at Uhcl, Delta building!");

    GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint((int) (sscbla * 1E6),
            (int) (sscblo * 1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Hello",
            "I'm at Uhcl, Student Services building!");

    GeoPoint point3 = new GeoPoint((int) (csbla * 1E6),
            (int) (csblo * 1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem3 = new OverlayItem(point3, "Hello",
            "I'm at Uhcl, Central Services building!");

    GeoPoint point4 = new GeoPoint((int) (arbourla * 1E6),
            (int) (arbourlo * 1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem4 = new OverlayItem(point4, "Hello",
            "I'm at Uhcl, Arbour building!");


    /*GeoPoint point5 = new GeoPoint((int) (bayoula * 1E6),
            (int) (bayoulo * 1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem4 = new OverlayItem(point5, "Hello",
            "I'm at Uhcl, Bayou building!");*/


    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem3);
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem4);
    //itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem5);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

    mapController.animateTo(point2);
    mapController.setZoom(17);

    compass = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(compass);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    compass.disableCompass();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    compass.enableCompass();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.uhcl.maps.StreetView
```

usually means that the class in question isn't in the CLASSPATH.  The class loader can't find it.

Is this a homework question?  Should you have a JAR from this site in your project somewhere?

http://prtl.uhcl.edu/portal/page/portal/HOMEPAGE/MAPS_DIRECTIONS/CampusMap

Comment: this is not a homework, its an app we are developing for college (it has maps and few others). Can you please be a bit more specific. it will be helpfull

Comment: No, I can't be more specific - you either understand what CLASSPATH means or you don't.  (Hint: You cannot program Java unless you understand CLASSPATH.)  Where is that class com.uhcl.maps.StreetView?  If you can't find it anywhere in your deployment, how do you expect the class loader to find it?

Comment: firstly you mistook it as a homework..! now you try to teach me what classpath is..? I exactly know what classpath means, I have other modules running successfully. if you don't know the solution just quit.don't intimidate me.

Comment: Hi Duffymo, I was looking at my old posts  don't know why, was just curious I guess. I now see how arrogant my reply was when you were only trying to help. I apologize.

Comment: So generous of you to say so. No apology needed.